# Let $(G,+)$ be an additive abelian group. If $a,b\in G$, need help to prove part (b) below:

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $(G,+)$ be an abelian group written in additive notation. If $\,a,\,b\in G,\,$ prove that:

$(a)$ The subset $\,S=\mathbb{Z}\cdot a + \mathbb{Z}\cdot b = \{k\cdot a+l\cdot b\mid k,l\in \mathbb{Z}\}\,$ is a subgroup of $\,(G,+)$.

$(b)$ $\,S\,$ is precisely the subgroup $\,H=\langle a,b\rangle\;$ generated by $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$.

I have proved the first part, but I have no clue how to prove part $(b)$. Please help me if anyone has a clue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall what it means for two elements to generate a subgroup: it means, in additive notation, that all integer multiples of $a$ and of $b$ are in the group they generate, and all linear combinations $k\cdot a + l\cdot b,\;\; k, l \in \mathbb Z$ are in $\langle a, b\rangle$, because, as a group, we must have closure under addition. To show $S$ is precisely the subgroup $H =\langle a, b\rangle$: show that

$$g \in \langle a, b\rangle \implies g \in S \;\;\text{and}\;\;g\in S \implies g \in \langle a, b \rangle$$

In doing so, you thereby show that $$\,\langle a, b \rangle \subseteq S \;\;\text { and}\;\;S \subseteq \langle a,b\rangle \quad \iff \quad S = \langle a, b\rangle$$

Comment: By definition, $\langle a,b\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup containing $a$ and $b$.

Comment: azimut: Exactly, and it must, under closure of a group, contain all integer multiples (the additive analog to all powers of an element) of $a$ and $b$ and of ab and $ka + ba$. Nothing I wrote suggests otherwise.

Comment: uhi: feel free to comment below if you're struggling and need more hints.

Comment: Your first version suggested that $\langle a,b\rangle = \mathbb{Z}\cdot a + \mathbb{Z}\cdot b$ by definition. The current formulation "Recall what it means for two elements to generate a subgroup..." still goes into this direction.

Comment: so if i am saying g$\in <a,b$>, does that equal to $g=k_{1}.a + l_{1}.b$ where $k_{1}$ and $l_{1}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ and that will imply $g \in S$. Is that correct, amWhy?

Comment: Yes, but put some more thought into why?  You need to spell out, in you work/argument for the problem, as hinted, what two elements generating a group means: what elements must necessarily be in $\langle a, b \rangle$. But yes, you've got the point...and vice versa, too (arguing backwards).

Comment: yes i am talking your hint as a jumping board and then for the subsequent proof, i am going to use this argument. Do you still think i would need to say something more?

Comment: Thanks it has been very helpful, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** In (b), you have to show the equation $S = \langle a,b\rangle$, which is an equation of two sets. Split the proof into the two inclusions $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$.